# Onclick of click select option should appear angular

Tags: angularjs

i have a link on page on click of that select option should appear for selection.
Link are created dynamically based on json response

```
<a href=\"#\" class='addMethod'>Add Member</a>
<a href=\"#\" class='addMethod'>Add Member</a>
<a href=\"#\" class='addMethod'>Add Member</a>
```

On Click on anchor link select option should come hiding the anchor on which it is clicked

```
<select >
<option value="1">Member</option>
<option value="2">Group</option>
<option value="3">Admin</option>
</select>
```

On selection in place of Add Member selected option should come.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-click` to insert choices into the select list:

```
<div ng-repeat="choice in choices | filter:unselected">
  <a ng-click="addRole(choice);">
    Add {{choice}}
  </a>
</div>

<select ng-model="role" ng-options="role for role in roles"></select>
```

Here is a working demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/jL5KFkxIqB0cwzblnQGh?p=preview